# ON April or IN April?

Tags: prepositions

When talking about months should I use the preposition "on" or "in"?

For instance,

> I am going to be there **on**/**in** April.

Comment: "*in* April" but "*on* April 15th"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand one of the comments, you would use "in April" because the day when you will arrive is within the month of April, but if you say a specific day, you would say "on April 15th".  The key is that using "in" means what you are referring to encompasses something else, while on usually refers to a specific day.

You would say that you wake up "in the morning" rather than "on the morning" since it is a more general time.  You would use "at" to describe an exact time, such as "at noon", or "at 5 o'clock" rather than "in 5 o'clock" or "in noon" or "on noon".

[Here](https://blog.udemy.com/in-vs-on/) is a helpful reference.

Comment: It would be better to close the question in favor of the more complete duplicate than to give an incomplete answer here. For instance, you would say you woke up *at night*, but not *at morning*, and while you wouldn't say *on morning*, you would say *on Tuesday morning*.  Depending on your dialect, you would say *on the weekend* or *at the weekend*; likewise, seeing my mother *at Easter* is somewhat different *on Easter*. And while we use *in* for most periods, like *in the reign of Tiberius* or *in the rainy season* or *in the future*, it doesn't work with *in the holidays* for example.